# Filtering issues in grid

Tags: arrays, angular, linq, typescript, logic

I have filtering pipe logic for grid search

```
results.filter(item => Object.keys(item)
          .some(key => searchTerm.split(',').some(arg =>item[key]? item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(arg.toString().toLowerCase()):""))
         );
```

The above code will search a keyword in all columns in the array list, which binds the grid, But i need not to search all columns in the array list.

I ONLY need to search the columns which are displayed in the grid.

So , logic will be like below:

```
results
          .filter(item => (item.ProxyName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || 
                            item.ProxyType.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())||
                            item.SA_SPOC_DL.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())||
                            item.AssignmentGroup.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
                  );
         .filter(item => Object.keys(item)
          .some(key => searchTerm.split(',').some(arg =>item[key]? item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(arg.toString().toLowerCase()):""))
         );
```

For this i decided to pass a comma separated array of columns to filter like

> string searchcolumns = ["ProxyName,ProxyType,SA_SPOC_DL"]

So if i pass comma seperated array of columns, how i rewrite the logic?

Answer (score 0):

I have not touched your other logic,just refactored the part where you need to use the columns.You just need to iterate through the column list:

```
const itemList: any[] = [
  { ProxyName: 'AG', AssignmentGroup: 'AG', ProxyType: 'PT', SA_SPOC_DL: 'SA2' },
  { ProxyName: 'B1', AssignmentGroup: 'AG123', ProxyType: 'AG', SA_SPOC_DL: 'SB2' },
  { ProxyName: 'C1', AssignmentGroup: 'AG', ProxyType: 'PT', SA_SPOC_DL: 'SC2' },
  { ProxyName: 'D1', AssignmentGroup: 'A', ProxyType: 'PT', SA_SPOC_DL: 'AG' },
  { ProxyName: 'E1', AssignmentGroup: 'AG', ProxyType: 'PT', SA_SPOC_DL: '' },
  { ProxyName: 'F1', AssignmentGroup: 'A', ProxyType: 'PT', SA_SPOC_DL: '' }
];

const searchColumns = ['ProxyName', 'ProxyType', 'SA_SPOC_DL', 'AssignmentGroup'];

const result = filterResult('AG', searchColumns, itemList);

function filterResult(searchTerm: String, searchcolumns: string[], results: any[]) {
  const resultSet: any[] = [];
  searchcolumns.forEach(column => {
    results.filter(item =>
      item[column].toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      && !resultSet.includes(column)
    ).filter(item => Object.keys(item)
      .some(key => searchTerm.split(',')
        .some(arg => item[key] ? item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(arg.toString().toLowerCase()) : '')))
      .forEach(element => { if (!resultSet.includes(element)) { resultSet.push(element); } });
  });

  return resultSet;
}
```

Comment: Only the last column in the array , search is working , not the other columns

Comment: searchcolumns.forEach(column => {
            filteredresults =results.filter(item => item[column]?item[column].toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()): '')
              .filter(item => Object.keys(item)
                .some(key => searchTerm.split(',')
                  .some(arg => item[key]
                    ? item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(arg.toString().toLowerCase()) : '')));

          })